# Logging to file

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren, maintenance-plans

I am using the ola-hallengren maintenance scripts.
I am logging to table and file.
I want to change the location of the file logs.
Can I do this?
Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Changing it per jobstep while keeping Ola's log naming convention**

You can change the location in the job step properties, opened with either *double clicking or pressing Edit*.

[image]

[image]

*Select Advanced*

[image]

And go to *Output File*

[image]

You will notice a string like:

```
$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))\DatabaseIntegrityCheck_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPID))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STRTDT))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STRTTM)).txt
```

Where you can change the `$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))` to your preferred location
If say, you would like to get the logs in `C:\temp`, then change it to:

```
C:\temp\DatabaseIntegrityCheck_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPID))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STRTDT))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STRTTM)).txt
```

*The string can vary depending on the purpose of the job step and your SQL Server version.*

*(SQL Server 2012 and above should get the same result)*

As a result, Ola's naming convention remains the same and log files will not be reused.

[image]

You have to remember to adapt the `OutputFileCleanup` Job

**From:**

```
cmd /q /c "For /F "tokens=1 delims=" %v In ('ForFiles /P "$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))" /m *_*_*_*.txt /d -30 2^>^&1') do if EXIST "$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))"\%v echo del "$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))"\%v& del "$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))"\%v
```

**To:**

```
cmd /q /c "For /F "tokens=1 delims=" %v In ('ForFiles /P "C:\temp" /m *_*_*_*.txt /d -30 2^>^&1') do if EXIST "C:\temp"\%v echo del "C:\temp"\%v& del "C:\temp"\%v"
```

Or in short, change the `$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))` parts to your specified folder.

---

**Changing it for all the jobs created by the MaintenanceSolution**

You can do this for the entire maintenance solution by adding the folder name to the `@OutputFileDirectory` parameter in the `MaintenanceSolution.SQL` [script](https://ola.hallengren.com/downloads.html).

```
SET @OutputFileDirectory = NULL         -- Specify the output file directory. If no directory is specified, then the SQL Server error log directory is used.
```

E.G

```
SET @OutputFileDirectory = 'C:\temp'
```

Validate the changed folder:

[image]

*If the jobs already exist, then you would have to recreate them, described below.*

---

**If the MaintenanceSolution jobs already exist**

If you need to change the log location for all the existing jobs, then you would have to update each of the steps, or drop the jobs and recreate them with Ola's script.

(Remember that scheduling, job state, ... **WILL** be removed from the job when dropping and creating them).

*Example query to drop the jobs:*

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'DatabaseBackup - SYSTEM_DATABASES - FULL')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'DatabaseBackup - SYSTEM_DATABASES - FULL'

IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = N'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - DIFF')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - DIFF'

IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = N'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - FULL')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - FULL'

IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = N'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - LOG')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - LOG'

IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = N'DatabaseIntegrityCheck - SYSTEM_DATABASES')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'DatabaseIntegrityCheck - SYSTEM_DATABASES'

IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = N'DatabaseIntegrityCheck - USER_DATABASES')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'DatabaseIntegrityCheck - USER_DATABASES'

IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = N'IndexOptimize - USER_DATABASES')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'IndexOptimize - USER_DATABASES'

IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'sp_purge_jobhistory')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'sp_purge_jobhistory'

IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'sp_delete_backuphistory')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'sp_delete_backuphistory'

IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'CommandLog Cleanup')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'CommandLog Cleanup'

IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'Output File Cleanup')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'Output File Cleanup'
```

Validate and rerun the Maintenance solution with

`SET @CreateJobs          = 'Y'`

Comment: Fantastic. I will edit each job as I want to change the location depending on the job so there is a file structure. Also I don't want to have to set all schedules again Will the cleanup job handle file structure like x:\logs\index, x:\logs\log_backup and x:\logs\full_backup etc? x:\ being original location just more structured now. All were being saved directly to x:\ and I want to add structure. Many thanks

Comment: @Round  No problem! I am not 100% with you here, the most important one to change is the `Output File Cleanup` job. If all logs are in `x:\logs` then simply change the output files in the jobsteps, and change the job, again replacing `$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))` with `x:\logs`. This should cleanup the logs for all the jobs. If you are going to put the job step outputs in different folders, then you might have to run the commands from the ` OutputFileCleanup` job a few times, for each folder (or change the command in an other way).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. This is the way I've done it in the past:

1. Select SQL Agent Job you want to change location of file logs
2. Steps > Edit > Advanced
3. Change the file path in the "Output file" section to where you want it to save to. You probably need to create the new folder structure ahead of time in the new location before setting the new path.

There might be a better way to change them all at once but I haven't done this before.

Comment: Remember to also change the CommandLog cleanup job for this.